# Lead Conversion apex class throwing error again and again

Tags: apex

I wrote an apex class which creates contacts then I am converting the lead where I am merging with the existing contact but I am getting the following error.

> LeadTrigger: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, accountId must be specified if contactId is not null: [Id] Class.LeadTriggerHandler.afterInsertProcess: line 84, column 1 Trigger.LeadTrigger: line 3, column 1

Can anyone helps me out in this issue here if possible.

```
public class LeadTriggerHandler {

   Static List<Lead> noParentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
   Static List<Lead> parentLeadList = new List<Lead>();
   Static List<Contact> insertConList = new List<Contact>();

  public static void afterInsertProcess(List<Lead> leadList){
List<hed__Relationship__c> insertRelationShipList = new List<hed__Relationship__c>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
for(Lead leadKey : leadList){

    if(leadKey.Parent_or_guardian__c == false){
        //list which contains Parent__c = false
        noParentLeadList.add(leadKey);
    }else{
        //list which contains Parent__c = true
        parentLeadList.add(leadKey);
    }
}

if(noParentLeadList != null && noParentLeadList.size() > 0)
    createContactNoParent(noParentLeadList);

if(parentLeadList != null && parentLeadList.size() > 0)
{
    Map<Id,List<Contact>> insertConMap = createContactParent(parentLeadList);
    List<String> acctListName =new List<String>();
    Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet = new Set<String>();
    //contact insert operation
    for(Id idk : insertConMap.keySet()){
        insertConList.addAll(insertConMap.get(idk));
    }
    insert insertConList;
    for(Lead l1:parentLeadList)
    {
        if(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null){
        acctListName.add(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
        }
        if(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        otherProgramsValueSet.addAll(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));
        }
    }

    //setting up inserted contact's Id in RelationShip__c object.
    for(Id IdKey : insertConMap.keySet()){

        hed__Relationship__c rel = new hed__Relationship__c(
            hed__Contact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
            hed__RelatedContact__c = insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(1).Id,
            hed__Type__c = 'Parent'
        );
        insertRelationShipList.add(rel);
        if(acctListName != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap1 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : acctListName]){
            accNamesToIdsMap1.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap1.values()){
              insertaffiliationList.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        if(otherProgramsValueSet != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : otherProgramsValueSet]){
            accNamesToIdsMap.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap.values()){
              insertaffiliationList.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        List<Id> LeadIds = new List<Id>();
        Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new Database.LeadConvert();
        Leadconvert.setLeadId(IdKey);
        LeadStatus Leads= [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(Leads.MasterLabel);
        Leadconvert.setAccountId(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).AccountId);
        Leadconvert.setContactId(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).Id);
        Leadconvert.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(TRUE); 
        Database.LeadConvertResult Leadconverts = Database.convertLead(Leadconvert);
        System.assert(Leadconverts.isSuccess());
    }
    insert insertRelationShipList;
    insert insertaffiliationList;
}
}

    public static Map<Id,List<Contact>> createContactParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){

Map<Id, List<Contact>> contactMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
List<Contact> conList=null;

for(Lead tmpLead : incomingLeadList){
        conList = new List<Contact>();
       Contact con = new Contact(
            LastName = tmpLead.LastName, 
            FirstName = tmpLead.FirstName,
           Email = tmpLead.Email
        );
        conList.add(con);

        con = new Contact(
            LastName = tmpLead.Parent_First_Name__c,
            FirstName = tmpLead.Parent_Last_Name__c,
            Email = tmpLead.Parent_Email__c
        );
        conList.add(con);           
        contactMap.put(tmpLead.id, conList);
   }
   return contactMap;
   }


  public static void createContactNoParent(List<Lead> incomingLeadList){

List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
for(Lead ldKey : incomingLeadList){

    Contact con = new Contact(
        LastName = ldKey.LastName,
        FirstName = ldKey.FirstName
    );
    contactList.add(con);
}
insert contactList;
List<String> acctListName2 =new List<String>();
    Set<String> otherProgramsValueSet2 = new Set<String>();
List<hed__Affiliation__c> insertaffiliationList2 = new List<hed__Affiliation__c>();
        for(Lead l1:noParentLeadList)
    {
        if(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c != null){
        acctListName2.add(l1.What_is_your_primary_program_of_interest__c);
        }
        if(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c != null){
        otherProgramsValueSet2.addAll(l1.Other_Programs_of_Interest__c.split(';'));
        }
    }
if(acctListName2 != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap2 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : acctListName2]){
            accNamesToIdsMap2.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap2.values()){
              insertaffiliationList2.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=contactList.get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Primary__c = true,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
        if(otherProgramsValueSet2 != null){
        Map<String,Id> accNamesToIdsMap3 = new Map<String,Id>();
        for(Account acc : [select id,Pardot_Program_Name__c from account where Pardot_Program_Name__c in : otherProgramsValueSet2]){
            accNamesToIdsMap3.put(acc.Pardot_Program_Name__c,acc.Id);
        }
            for(Id accId : accNamesToIdsMap3.values()){
              insertaffiliationList2.add(new hed__Affiliation__c(hed__Account__c= accId,
                                                       hed__Contact__c=contactList.get(0).Id,
                                                       hed__Role__c='Prospect'));
            }
        }
     insert insertaffiliationList2;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Try to only post relevant code, rather than doing a whole code dump. You'll get more community help if your question and code are more focused

Comment: Please take some time to format your code with clean indentation and whitespace so that it can be read. Most Java formatters can help with Apex, or the Developer Console. Please clearly identify the line with the error, and remove any code from your post that is not involved in this issue.

Comment: @BrianMiller, I am not getting any error in code, its saving but while cerating the record, I am getting the issue so i posted whole code

Comment: @DavidReed, I am not getting any error in code, its saving but while cerating the record, I am getting the issue so i posted whole code

Answer (score 3):

The error is because the AccountId value in this line is null:

```
Leadconvert.setAccountId(insertConMap.get(IdKey).get(0).AccountId);
```

This is because your `createContactParent()` method doesn't set the AccountId of the contacts you are creating.  You will need to create or retrieve the appropriate account for each contact before you do the `convertLead`.